# Aptly: package in repo but can't be installed

Tags: apt, repository

I'm setting up a repo by doing the following:

```
aptly repo create sample_repo
aptly repo add sample_repo neuboxdb-0.9.0-amd64.deb
aptly snapshot create sample_snapshot from repo sample_repo
aptly publish snapshot sample_snapshot
aptly serve
```

The web server starts on port `8080`.

I then add the following to `sources.list` on a x86-64 machine:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://[ip address of server:8080/ xenial universe
```

Next I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Which returns:

```
W: http://[server ip]:8080/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key EB45DBC87E77FEA9CB66C1D13FB76626D9985912 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

But when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install neuboxdb
```

I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package neuboxdb
```

Looking in `/var/lib/apt/lists` on the machine I'm installing onto, I see an `InRelease` file corresponding to the server, but no *amd64_Packages* file.

On the repo machine, `~/.aptly/public/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64` contains an entry for `neuboxdb`.

What's not right with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a nice tool to know about thank you. Well, could you compare these:

> `sources.list` on on x86-64 machine:
>
> ```
> deb [arch=amd64] http://[ip address of server]:8080/ xenial universe
> ```
>
> ...
>
> On the repo machine,
>
> ```
> ~/.aptly/public/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64
> ```

See the component, it is not the same, so your `sources.list` should have something like:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://[ip address of server]:8080/ xenial main
```